# Get the latest records from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables in a SQLite3 database. I want a **result of one row** (for a json string) **with the latest record of Humidity and Temperature from each DeviceID** which means two records from Temperature and one from Humidity.

The three readings are inserted at the same time so finding one `MAX(Timestamp)` and then look for other records with the same timestamp works.

The result should look like this:

```
Timestamp   H   C   C
1545732002  50  25  25
```

The closest I can get so far is this:

```
SELECT max(Humidity.Timestamp), Humidity.H, Temperature.C, CoolTemp.C
FROM Temperature, Humidity
INNER JOIN Devices AS DeviceHum ON Humidity.DeviceID = DeviceHum.DeviceID
INNER JOIN Temperature AS CoolTemp ON Temperature.Timestamp = Humidity.Timestamp`
```

Which gives me the latest H and C from Device 1 but not the latest C from Device 2. This also takes 19 seconds to run.

I can't get my head around this.

The database itself --> [logtest.db at file.io](https://file.io/c371FL) 307,2kB

Tables look like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your sample data as a bunch of insert statements or CSV or something else trivial to add to a database for testing instead of as images?

Comment: I added a link to downloading the  .db, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting one.

I can't make promises about speed: that would depend in part on what indexes you have and how many records.  But I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT Hum.Timestamp, 
       Hum.H,
       Hot.C,
       Cool.C
FROM Humidity as Hum
  INNER JOIN Temperature Hot
    ON Hum.Timestamp = Hot.Timestamp and Hot.DeviceId = 1
  INNER JOIN Temperature Cool
    ON Hum.Timestamp = Cool.Timestamp and Cool.DeviceId = 2
WHERE Hum.Timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(Humidity.Timestamp)
    FROM   Humidity
    )
```

This will work for the case of exactly two devices.  If you have more than two, esp. if you have an arbitrary number, this becomes more of a "rotation problem" (query the values, then turn them sideways), and I don't know if `SQLite` has a built-in solution for that.

Comment: Excellent, this got me exactly what I wanted. I got the result in 15ms.
There wont be any more devices.
Now I'm gonna try to understand what you did :)

Comment: @AlexBergsland Glad it helped!  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @AlexBergsland As an addendum: because I used inner joins, if you ever have a timestamp missing for Devices 1 or 2, that entire row will drop out.  Same if the Humidity table is missing a timestamp.  BUT, if your data is always complete, and all 3 records exist for every timestamp, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamps are indeed the same, you can use a correlated subquery to get the latest timestamp:

```
select . . .
from temperature t join
     humidity h
     on t.deviceid = h.deviceid and t.timestamp = h.timestamp
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from temperature t2
                     where t2.deviceid = t.deviceid
                    );
```